# How can i loop through a Collection in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have a  Matrix and i want to print the rows of it.
I tried to implement it like this but i dont know how to loop and get the other elements!

```
(defn p! [args]
 (println (first args))
 (drop args))

(p! [[1 2] [3 4]]) --> [1 2]

the output should look like this 
;; 12
;; 34
```

Comment: (doseq [row args] (println row))

Comment: Or if you really want the exact output you posted `(doseq [row args] (println (clojure.string/join row)))`

Comment: @modar Have you learnt to use [loop](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/loop)? I would suggest learning to loop on the simplest possible example before trying something more complex.

Comment: `(clojure.pprint/cl-format true "~{~{~a~}~%~}" [[1 2] [3 4]])` would do the trick )

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [core.matrix](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix) facilities for this task. It has a mature and time-tested API. Among other things, it provides you with a `pm` function that pretty-prints a matrix and accepts a custom element `formatter` as a parameter.

You might find [its implementation](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix/blob/0a35f6e3d6d2335cb56f6f3e5744bfa1dd0390aa/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/matrix/impl/pprint.clj#L92) interesting, since it can give you an idea of printing array-like structures. (TL;DR: It approaches it with a recursive algorithm that employs a `dotimes` fn quite heavily.)

With this library you might end up implementing your `p!` fn like this:

```clj
(require '[clojure.core.matrix :as mx])

(defn p! [args]
  (mx/pm (mx/matrix args)))

(p! [[1 2] [3 4]])
[[1 2]
 [3 4]]
=> nil
```

If you would like to keep things simple and/or omit the brackets, then the easiest implementation would be along these lines:

```clj
(defn p! [args]
  (doseq [row args]
    (println (clojure.string/join " " row))))

(p! [[1 2] [3 4]])
1 2
3 4
=> nil
```

Cheers!